# gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

Tags: nativescript

i am very new to nativescript, i try to build my first app in nativescript, but it shows

=============================================================================
C:\Nativescript\Grab1>

C:\Nativescript\Grab1>tns prepare android
Executing before-prepare hook from C:\Nativescript\Grab1\hooks\before-prepare\na
tivescript-dev-android-snapshot.js
Preparing project...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further detail
s.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.
  Processing node_modules failed. Error: Command C:\Nativescript\Grab1\platforms\a
  ndroid\gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

C:\Nativescript\Grab1>

================================================================================

here i attached my command prompt screen shot also, please help me to solve this problem friends

[image]

Comment: Try clearing the project platforms and node_moudles folders, some times when you interrupt an build the next time you trigger it there where "cached" files that are no longer correct because of the previous build interrupt. Also can you share some code of your project or is it a "hello world" project, is it Angular or ?

Comment: Of course it is simple hellow world app from native script tutorial I didn't add any code in this app and I got this error at first time of project built.

Comment: Which version of NativeScript do you have installed?

Comment: I still face this issue today and none of the answers given work

Answer (score 20):

It seems some files missing in `platform -> android` folder. I fixed this issue by removing the android platform and adding it again by using the below command:

Make sure you are in project directory.Then try this below two commands:

```
tns platform remove android

tns platform add android
```

Same way for IOS:

```
tns platform remove ios

tns platform add ios
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if someone out there is having the same problem on MacOS systems

1. tns platform remove iOS
2. tns platform add iOS

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the platform folder from the root directory of the project and run

> tns run android

I guess Gradle keeps the history logs which is creating the error. So we need to delete that and rebuild the project.

Comment: What is the platform folder?